# How can I create wizards in spring rcp using netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, spring-rcp

I created forms by extending AbstractForm class,now I want to create wizards but I am facing problem in it,can you help me  creating wizards in spring-rcp using netbeans from start

Answer (score 0):

1.create more than one form(refer http://netbeans.dzone.com/news/getting-further-with-spring-rc)

2.after that create child class of AbstractWizard.Initialize your forms on class load and then use method  addForm(Object);
like addForm(form1); addForm(form2);

3.In your view class override createControl method,create object of your wizard class and then 
call showDialog method.
        Your wizards starts.